# Best practice to implement a boolean macro argument?

Tags: macros, conditionals, best-practices

Sometimes I'd like a macro to depend on a boolean argument but I don't know about the best way to implement this. So far, I end up introducing a global (say) `\newif\ifextra` that is used inside the macro but that needs to be set each time before the macro is called.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newif\ifextra
\def\showcase{Show a sentence. \ifextra And a little more if asked to. \fi}

\begin{document}
        \extratrue\showcase 
        \extrafalse\showcase
\end{document}
```

From a programming perspective it would be better to pass the flag as an argument rather than relying on a global flag. What is the best practice here?

Addendum: [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s answer highlights that this can also be understood as implementing two variants of a macro, like `\showcase` and `\showcase*`, where the flag is encoded into the name (technically it's not, but that is how it looks).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a *-variant:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{s}{%
  Show a sentence.%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{ And a little more if asked to.}%
}
```

Now `\showcase` will produce the short version and `\showcase*` the long one. Just change `\IfBooleanT` into `\IfBooleanF` for the reverse. There's also `\IfBooleanTF` that accepts two texts.

The variant indicator can be different: if you say

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{t+}{...}
```

then the variant will be `\showcase+`.

---

### The "classical" method

Using "pure LaTeX" one can say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showcase}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\@showcase{ And a little more if asked to.}}
    {\@showcase{}}%
}
\newcommand{\@showcase}[1]{Show a sentence.#1}
\makeatother
```

This version of `\showcase` would be fragile and `\DeclareRobustCommand` would be needed for defining it in case it's supposed to appear in moving arguments (or it should be preceded by `\protect`). So two macros must be defined (three in case `\DeclareRobustCommand` is used), instead of the only one with `xparse`.

In this case, to be honest, a simpler method would work:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showcase}{Show a sentence.%
  \@ifstar{ And a little more if asked to.}{}}
\makeatother
```

because you don't want to grab arguments. But this would fail if you want something like

```
 \showcase{b}
 \showcase*{b}
```

to produce

> Show b sentence.
>   Show b sentence. And a little more if asked to.

respectively. You'll have to do with the auxiliary macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showcase}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\@showcase{ And a little more if asked to.}}
    {\@showcase{}}%
}
\newcommand{\@showcase}[2]{Show #2 sentence.#1}
\makeatother
```

To work properly, `\@ifstar{...}{...}` must be *last* in a replacement text.

With `xparse` you'd do

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{sm}{%
  Show #2 sentence.%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{ And a little more if asked to.}%
}
```

### Other methods

There are other packages that allow for defining macros with variants, for instance `suffix`:

```
\usepackage{suffix}
\newcommand{\showcase}{Show a sentence.}
\WithSuffix\def\showcase*{%
  \csname\NoSuffixName\showcase\endcsname{} And a little more if asked to.}
```

The syntax is not very friendly in either case.

Comment: You could of course do the * variant without xparse/LaTeX3.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub Yes, but I believe that this is the most practical way. I'll add something.

Comment: Could the classical method be simplified to `\def\showcase{Show a sentence. \@ifstar{And show some more.}{}}`? Or does `\@ifstar` has to come at the beginning of the macro being star'ed? A first test suggests this works but I wonder about the general case.

Comment: @ChristianLindig In this case you can do that simplification, because you don't have to grab arguments for `\showcase`. The important thing is that `\@ifstar{}{}` comes *last* in the replacement text. I'll show it with an example.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for continuously extending your answer! (In your updated example there is no `\@ifstar` any more which is just a bug, I assume.)

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newif\ifextra
\newcommand\showcase[1][1]{Show a sentence.
   \ifnum#1=1 \extratrue\else\extrafalse\fi
   \ifextra And a little more if asked to. \fi}
\begin{document}
        \showcase[0] \\
        \showcase[1]
\end{document}
```

I have used 1 as *true* and any other number as *false* for providing a condensed syntax.

As noted in the comments, if the switch `\ifextra` is not used outside a macro you can drop it.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand\showcase[1][0]{Show a sentence.
   \ifnum#1=1 And a little more if asked to. \fi}
\begin{document}
   \showcase\\
   \showcase[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\ifnum .. \else ..\fi` directly and drop `\ifextra`? Any drawback? My takeaway is that you are using numbers as argument because they work well together with `\ifnum`.

Comment: @ChristianLindig You can do that as well. I kept it as close to your original syntax as possible in case you using the boolean outside macros.

Comment: `\extra` is only global because I didn't know of a better way. So there is no use of it outside the macro and I'd now use `\ifnum` directly.

Comment: @ChristianLindig Thanks for the clarification, I added a note as well to the answer to make it clearer.